# Is it possible to limit Stripe Charges by metadata?

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I have a paginated charge list like this:

```
stripelist = Stripe::Charge.list({limit: 100})

stripelist.each do |payment|
    if payment["metadata"]["ss_registration"]
        striperecords << payment if pendingrecs.include? payment.metadata.portal_payment_id
    end
end

while stripelist.has_more do 
    stripelist = Stripe::Charge.list({limit: 100, starting_after: stripelist.data.last.id})
    stripelist.each do |payment|
        if payment["metadata"]["ss_registration"]
            striperecords << payment if pendingrecs.include? payment.metadata.portal_payment_id
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that I have to pull all charges and then filter the results in Ruby, which costs processing time.  Is there a way to filter by metadata?... to do something like this at the start:

```
stripelist = Stripe::Charge.list({limit: 100}, metadata: '{ss_registration}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't list Charges by their metadata. Right now the only parameters that you can list Charges by are listed here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=ruby

But, your code could be simplified a bit by using Stripe's auto-pagination functionality; described here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=ruby.

With auto-pagination, your code could boil down to something like:

```
charges = Stripe::Charge.list({ limit: 100 })

charges.auto_paging_each do |charge|
  if charge["metadata"]["ss_registration"]
    striperecords << charge if pendingrecs.include? charge.metadata.portal_payment_id
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried your much more elegant approach: it works.  It doesn't save any processing time at all but at least it is leaner looking.  :)  Thaks again.

Answer (score 0):

Strive Development will consider adding metadata as charge criteria.  Here's their response to my request:

> Thank you for reaching out to us, and give us your feedback to improve
>   our API charges, we know it is important for the businesses.
>
> We're always working to make Stripe better for our users, so it's
>   valuable to hear your input. We understand you want our development
>   team to code for limiting meta data in addition to the transfer group
>   and our development team will consider it.

If you have any questions, feel free to contact us!